# Exception at launch for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure

I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector in my .NET 4.6.2 WPF app but when I start my app, I have a Win32Exception coming from SnapshotCollector which tells me a file is missing.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
    à System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    à System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
    à System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    à Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Start(Guid datacube, String endpoint, IWorkingFolders workingFolders)
    à Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<StartAsync>b__0()
    à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
    à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.StampFrontEnd.<GetStampIdAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.ServiceProfilerClient.<ConnectToStampAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
    --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor.<ConnectAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
```

The app then continues to launch and works fine but I don't think SnapshotCollector is working.

I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger) to configure SnapshotCollector for my "other .NET applications" section.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

By default, NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector installs its files in the SnapshotCollectorFiles folder inside bin/x86/Debug, but these files need to be in the same root folder than the executable app.